# Non-linear Wave Equation - Numerical Methods

Tags: differential-equations, non-linear-systems, numerical-method

**Motivation:**

I'm working with a highly non-linear spherical wave-like equation (second order PDE). The equation can be written on the form

$$\ddot{u} = f(t, \dot{u},\dot{u}',u',u'')$$

where $'=\frac{d}{dr}$ and $\dot{} =\frac{d}{dt}$. (The expression for the function $f$ is long to I don't include it, but it contains terms like $\dot{u}^nu'^m$.)

I need to solve this numerically, and I have done this by defining the 'velocity' $Q = \frac{du}{dt}$ so that we can write the system as

$$\dot{Q} = f(t, Q, Q', u' ,u'')$$
$$\dot{u} = Q$$

which I then discretize on a grid (for the space) and evolve in time using a a staggered leapfrog:

$$Q_{n+1/2} = Q_{n-1/2} + f(t_n, Q_n, Q'_n, u'_n ,u''_n)\Delta t$$
$$u_{n+1} = u_n + Q_{n+1/2}\Delta t$$

This works fine for many applications, but I have some problems with getting this to work in all situations I'm interested in.

**Question**

I'm therefore looking for alternative methods to solve this equation. I welcome any suggestions. I have been thinking about Newton-Gauss-Seidel, but it's pretty computationally expensive so I'm hoping there are other methods I could try first. Also, if there is someone that has experience with numerically solving such equations it would be great to get some input on methods that are known to work well in practice.

Comment: What kind of problems are you running into with the leapfrog method? It might be discretization errors (i.e., $\Delta t$ too big).

Comment: It is a bit hard to explain, but the equation I'm solving has some sort of 'critial' phenomenon for certain setups (depending on the source that drives the system) that I'm unable to integrate past. The equation can also be written $\dot{u} = \frac{A(t,\dot{u},\ldots)}{B(t,\dot{u},\ldots)}$ and I have problems when $B$ gets close to zero. In the solution I get $B$ crosses zero (which is non-sensical) no matter how small time-step I choose. I have arguments for why the solution should exist so I therefore suspect I need more hardcore methods to get past this point.

Comment: I see. Well, the Crank-Nicolson method is often used for 2nd-order PDEs, as are matrix methods such as Least-Squares and Conjugate Gradient. There's also the Alternating Direction Explicit method (not to be confused with the of-cited Alternating Direction Implicit method) and Super-Time-Stepping methods (which is really a Chebychev-Runge-Kutta method).

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I will try there too if I don't get any feedback, but for this sort of problems its most likely that a physicist has done this before (or something similar) so I prefer to keep it here for now.

Comment: @KyleKanos I have not heard about the Super-Time-Stepping methods before so I will check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Liouville mapping or [PIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle-in-cell) simulations?  Regardless, these both use methods that sound similar to what you are describing (though I am an experimentalist, so _cum grano salis_).